# Problem booting Kubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, kubuntu

So I installed Kubuntu the day before yesterday but when I start my laptop it boots right into Windows.
This is how I installed Kubuntu:

I downloaded the Kubuntu 14.10 Plasma 4 release from the official Kubuntu-webpage.
I burnt it on a USB-stick with Universal-USB-Installer.
I changed the boot order on my Toshiba Satellite NB10-A-10U with Windows 8.1 already installed.
I let the installer take the most automatet choices.

Now when i finished it doesnt show the grub menu or the likes. I can of course boot the Live-Stick Kubuntu but not the one I installed. i search on the internet but either the instructions were too complicated for me and everyone seems to have a different solution.
I dont know much about booting. When I installed Ubuntu on my pc ( yes, also dual boot ) everything worked out just fine.

Comment: Try the answer here: http://askubuntu.com/a/88432/187281

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your computer boots up, hit the key that brings up `Boot From` menu and select your hard disk.Next it will prompt you to select either Windows or Ubuntu to boot from .

Comment: The problem is that it just boots right into windows. No "Ubuntu or Windows" prompt. Plus there is only one Hard disk.

Comment: To prevent booting straight to windows , press a key to `Boot from a device` and select your harddisk [even if there is one] where you installed Ubuntu and you would get the option to select the 2 OS. 
Once you are in Ubuntu ,download `Ubuntu boot repair` and select `Automatic Repair` which should bring back your `GRUB` menu.

If you can't boot into ubuntu , try using a live Ubuntu Disk and do the `Boot Repair`